# Calculate week number of the month, Sunday as Starting and Saturday as ending day Using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to calculate week number of the month using MS SQL sample input and output given below

```
01/04/2016(Friday)  1 (1st week),
04/04/2016(Monday)  2 (2nd week), 
11/04/2016(Monday)  3 (3rd week)
```

I need output like this
Consider Sunday as week starting date and Saturday as week ending date
I think this examples are clear

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server - they have different date/time functions. (none of then ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: And it must be a stored procedure?

Comment: @jarlh I am using MS SQL

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to get the output you are looking for -- I'm simply not sure what it means.  However, you can set the first day of the week using `DATEFIRST`.  This applies to most of the functions, such as `DATEPART`.

The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

for MySQL

select (dayofmonth(current_date)-weekday(current_date))/7+1

PostgreSQL

select (extract(day from current_date)-extract(dow from current_date))/7 +1;

just put your date in the current_date

Comment: ...and sql-server, which is what the question is based on?

Comment: when i post the answer there was mysql , just change the dayofmonth and weekday functions